# How can I show the question that have the most answers by Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum project, and in this project, I have a table named `questions` which holds data of questions that have been asked, like this:

[image: capture]

And another table named `answers` that holds answers of those questions based on `question_id`:

[image: capture 2]

Now I want to show the questions that have the most answers.

I don't really know how to do that using Eloquent, so if you know please tell me, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have a Model for `Question`, `Answer` and a relationship between them? Please show what you've tried and any errors you're experiencing.

Comment: Did you read the manual yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount` as demonstrated in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models. You can then use `orderBy` to sort them the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$topAnswered = Answers::query()
             ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as cnt'))
             ->groupBy('answers.question_id')
             ->orderBy('cnt')
             ->get();
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dbname.answers.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, count(*) as cnt from `answers` group by `answers`.`question_id` order by `cnt` asc)`

Comment: @tejoslaeslio `select *, count(answers.id) as cnt from answers`